# System of equations for semi-unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a semi unitary matrix $A_{i,j}$ with $1 \leq j \leq N$,  $1 \leq i \leq M$ and $M\geq N$, i.e. $A^\dagger A = I$.
I now have a set $N$ equations for the squared entries of each row:
$$\sum_j |A_{i,j}|^2 = n_i.$$
Is there a unique solution for this equation and if so, how do I find it? If it is not unique, can I construct at least one solution?

Or stated differently: if I only now that $$\sum_j |A_{i,j}|^2 = n_i,$$ can I create a semi-unitary matrix from this?

Comment: What is a semi-unitary matrix?

Comment: A semi-unitary matrix is a non-square matrix which fulfils either $A^\dagger A = I$ or $AA^\dagger=I$. In my case (more rows than columns) $A^\dagger A = I$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-orthogonal_matrix